# PhpStorm problem with recognizing namespaces, models and controllers

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I have some problem with my PhpStorm (ver 2020.2). You can see on pictures, models, controllers and namespaces aren't recognized by PhpStorm, but application is working perfect.

Someone knows how to fix that problem in PhpStorm?

[image: Namespaces]

[image: Controllers]

Comment: 1) What the warning/error is? What does it show when you hover over? Show a screenshot of it) 2) Have you tried `File | Invalidate Caches` and restart IDE?

Comment: Error is: undefined class (for controllers and models) and undefined namespace (for namespaces).

Comment: I tried File | Invalidate Caches but nothing happens. Same problem.

Comment: Did you do that with IDE restarting? If you did -- try manually deleting the cache, see instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64071021/783119 . If still nothing -- try disabling ALL custom (not bundled by default) plugins -- some of them may cause similar kind of issues.

Comment: I solved with answer below and it works. Thanks a lot man for helping me. :)

Answer (score 14):

For me, the solution was to close IDE from `File > Close Project`, then remove .idea folder `rm -rf .idea` from terminal, and finally reopening it fixed the issue.

Comment: It  restored the  problem again after a while. But then, when it suggests to put the folders  of project and  IDE as excluded for antivirus checks I didnt pickup Automatically . Chose Manually instead. And now its allright

Answer (score 7):

You have to define the namespaces in the `Settings`
Go to Settings > Directories and edit the properties for each namespace
[image]

On the `Source Folders` edit the prefix to be `App\`

[image]