# PhpStorm can't find DateTime

Tags: php, phpstorm

For some reason PhpStorm can't find the default PHP's `DateTime` class.

[image: use statement]

I'm using PHP 7.4 it's also set up in the IDE settings. I cleared cache and reindexed the IDE, but it still shows it in yellow. Also when I click on import it shows only DateTime classes from 3rd Party libraries.

I also tried `\DateTime` with the same result.

[image: import]

[image: \DateTime]

Comment: DateTime is a core class, in that case "use DateTime" is unnecessary

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/64071021/783119

Comment: @LazyOne thanks will try that out

Comment: @AdamP. I tried both ways you can either use "use" or write a "\" infront of the class to use php standart lib classes as far as I know

Comment: @nanobot Have you managed to resolve your issue? If you did -- was it the link I gave you?

Comment: @LazyOne yes that fixed it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment from : @LazyOne fixed it for me

> Check [stackoverflow.com/a/64071021/783119](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64071021/9560200)

delete the chache folder: `~/.cache/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.3/caches`

Answer (score 2):

The previous version of PhpStorm (2020.3.0) had a few issues linking associated files. I imagine it could cause this issue. Are you on the latest version (2020.3.1)?