# PhpStorm v2020.3.1 doesn't recognize PHP core functions like count

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have core PHP functions in my project but below of the PhpStorm it says `Undefined function strtolower`, `count` and so on.

In the left side `External Libraries > PHP Runtime` all the directories are collapsed and empty. I have cleared caches by `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...` but no luck.

[image: PHP Runtime]

[image: Undefined functions]

How to fix it?

Comment: Delete your IDE caches while IDE is closed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64071021/783119 for details (adjust the path for 2020.3 version). P.S. If you have installed PhpStorm via JetBrains Toolbox App .. then the path might be a bit different (check idea.log for that, it lists it at the start of the session)

Comment: Thank you very much :) The link mentioned fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete **.idea** folder. I had this problem 1 week ago.

Comment: I had deleted. No luck :(

Comment: Delete this folder :  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStormxxx\caches