# PhpStorm does not recognize PHP functions

Tags: php, phpstorm

PhpStorm does not recognize PHP built in functions like `count()`, `urldecode()`, `str_replace()` etc. So **many annoying warnings** shows on each file & **auto_complete** does not work.

PhpStorm v2020.3

I've tried Invalidate caches / restart, deleting PhpStorm cache folder and also disabled all 3rd party plugins. But this problem exists yet.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a namespace issue. What happens if you write `\str_replace`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64071021/783119 -- fixed properly in 2021.1.1. For 2020.3 only manual deletion of the cache/index folders helps

Comment: @Barmar Nothing happens!

Comment: See the linked question, that's probably it.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks. I've seen this link & I tried to delete cache & index folders manually again but it did not fix.

Comment: @SeyedAmirKhalifehSoltani 1) So what did you do **exactly?** Step by step (in case something was missing). What paths were used. 2) Try 2021.1.1 version

Comment: @LazyOne I closed Phpstorm. Delete caches & index folder form C:\Users\{my_user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm2020.3\ directory. restart Phpstorm. It did not fixed. Because  the Phpstorm php interpreter didn't set correctly! After set interpreter and following above steps it fixed. Thanks anyway! Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. PhpStorm **Php interpreter** did not set correctly. After set interpreter and delete manually "caches" & "index" folders and restart Phpstorm it fixed successfully!

C:\Users{my_user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm2020.3\caches
C:\Users{my_user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm2020.3\index

Comment: That's unexpected. Perhaps there is a bug .. as you do not need an actual PHP Interpreter for writing PHP code (unless it's a bug, of course). *My guess** is that it may be related to the bad selection of stub files (by mistake or whatnot) on PHP Runtime tab (a tab next to PHP Interpreter selector) -- they define what PHP core functions/classes/etc are known to the IDE.